# .NET 4.0: System.Threading.Tasks: Can I execute an array of tasks without them being threaded?

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, .net-4.0, task

I have this code:

```
Dim Tasks As New List(Of Task)

Tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub()
                                    'Do whatever
                                End Sub))

Tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub()
                                    'Do some stuff here
                                End Sub))

Tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub()
                                    'Do more code
                                End Sub))

Task.WaitAll(Tasks.ToArray())
```

This is being done in an ASP.NET application and is causing problems in production.  I want to disable the task threading so that all the anonymous methods execute consecutively, but this means rewriting the code to turn the anonymous methods into actual methods and then calling them.  It would really be nice if there were setting that would cause the collection of tasks to not behave in such a threaded manner.  Is this possible?

Comment: Out of interest, what problems is this causing?

Comment: Haven't figured it out.  It's a random exception of `Thread was being aborted.`.  What I am doing is firing off a bunch of threads that open connections, but it dies at random spots.

Comment: Sounds odd. How many concurrent requests are you handling? It seems unlikely, but I'm wondering if ASP.NET is running out of thread pool threads.

Comment: Not sure how many concurrent requests, but I am sure it is related to that.  I was under the impression that, if the threadpool was full, it would wait until it is available again.  Perhaps this is the reason why we're getting connection timeout issues.  It's waiting too long for the pool to empty, resulting in the timeout issues.  That's only theoretical.

Comment: Connection timeouts? I think there's more to this than multi-threading. What ORM / database are you using? Can you set the max concurrent connections in your connection string?

Comment: Teradata database.  Looking into the max concurrent connections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to use the [RunSynchronously](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321435.aspx) method of the Task.

Comment: Made this extension method:

    <Extension()>
    Sub WaitAsync(Tasks As IEnumerable(Of System.Threading.Tasks.Task))

        For Each Task As System.Threading.Tasks.Task In Tasks
            Task.RunSynchronously()
        Next

    End Sub

When I call it, I get the exception of `RunSynchronously may not be called on task that was already started.`.  Any ideas?  Google has extremely minimal support for this.

Comment: Marking as answer because I can't delete the quesiton.  Went another route and abandoned this method.

Comment: I don't think this should be the considered the answer just because you can't delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by providing a custom task scheduler. I am not certain at what position you have to inject it, probably at the factory level.